# In Rails is dividing helpers into different files just aesthetic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, Chapter 8, where a sign_in method is defined in helpers/sessions_helper.rb. I was surprised by the tutorial that this method could be called in the users controller, since users has its own helper users_helper.rb. Can any controller call any method in any helper file, and if so is it important to not use the same method names in different helper files?

Comment: somewhat off-topic but this practice that he uses in the tutorial is *not* a good one - helpers in the /app/helpers folder are meant for views only. Including them in controllers is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that helpers in different files is mainly aesthetic, but also that if you wish to use a specific helper in a specific controller, you'll be able to call that using its own name:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyHelper
end
```

With this in mind, it gives you some modularity, allowing you make your helper calls more efficient. However, in the grand scheme, most of the helpers are called each time your app renders views etc

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyHelper
end
```

All controllers are classes. All helpers are modules.

You have to require the file and include the module in the class to access the methods defined in the helper.

Rails: Helper files are included by default in the respective views. So, methods defined in `users_helper.rb` are directly available in the files in `views/users`.

MHartl's tutorial: `SessionsHelper` is included in `class ApplicationController`. `UsersController` ( for that matter any controller ) inherits from `ApplicationController`. So the modules included in `ApplicationController` are basically available in any controller.

> so is it important to not use the same method names in different helper files?

It's your wish. Just remember that the methods loaded later will override previous methods with the same name.
Eg.

Two modules describe a method `def can_do`.
I `include Module1`
and later `include Module2`

Any code after this that makes a call to `can_do` will actually call `Module2#can_do` and NOT `Module1#can_do`.